# Dynamically resizing CMFCPropertySheet with PropSheetLook_OneNoteTabs style

Tags: mfc, mfc-feature-pack

I'm trying to resize dynamically a `CMFCPropertySheet` to add a custom control at the bottom of each page.

As all Property Pages are not of the same height, I have a mechanism to increase the size if necessary.
For this, I have overridden the `OnActivatePage` method and by using `SetWindowPos`, I can resize the sheet, first, then the tab control, then the page and finally I can move the OK/Cancel/Help buttons.

It works fine with `PropSheetLook_OutlookBar` and `PropSheetLook_Tabs` styles but not with `PropSheetLook_OneNoteTabs` style. The page (or the tab) is not correctly resized (the lighter grey color of the page does not fill the sheet.

OneNote style [OneNote http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/th.ec91600664.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/th.ec91600664.jpg)

Outlook style [Outlook http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/th.319b6938ab.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/th.319b6938ab.jpg)

Any idea? A MFC Feature Pack bug?

Comment: What do the top edges of the pages look like?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.  One needs to get a reference to the different tab control the `OneNote` version uses via `GetTab()` and resize it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the instructions as seen in [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300606).
Although the instructions are for **CPropertySheet** they work for the **CMFCPropertySheet** as well.

Some parts of the code is deprecated so you will need to make the following amendments.

1. Skip the **XmnPropSheetCallback** and **DoModal** implementations completely
2. In `OnInitDialog` just make a call to `CPropertySheet::OnInitDialog();` and then call `OnSize` instead of doing everything presented in that code.