# Resizing property sheet is affecting the outlook bar dimensions

Tags: mfc, propertysheet

This is my `OnSize` method for resizing a property sheet:

```
void CResizingMFCPropertySheet::OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy)
{
    CMFCPropertySheet::OnSize(nType, cx, cy);

    if (!GetActivePage()) return;
    if (!GetTabControl()) return;

    if (nType == SIZE_MINIMIZED)
        return;

    int dx = cx - save_rc.Width();
    int dy = cy - save_rc.Height();

    int count = 0;
    for (CWnd *child = GetWindow(GW_CHILD); child; child = child->GetWindow(GW_HWNDNEXT))
        count++;

    HDWP hDWP = ::BeginDeferWindowPos(count);

    for (CWnd *child = GetWindow(GW_CHILD); child; child = child->GetWindow(GW_HWNDNEXT))
    {
        bool move = false;

        //If you add child controls manually, you want to move not resize
        if(child == &m_lblResize && m_lblResize.GetSafeHwnd() != nullptr)
            move = true;

        CRect r;
        child->GetWindowRect(&r);
        ScreenToClient(&r);

        if (move || child->SendMessage(WM_GETDLGCODE) & DLGC_BUTTON)
        {
            //move the main buttons and the child controls
            r.left += dx;
            r.top += dy;
            ::DeferWindowPos(hDWP, child->m_hWnd, 0, r.left, r.top, 0, 0,
                SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
        }
        else
        {
            //this must be a child window, resize it
            r.right += dx;
            r.bottom += dy;
            ::DeferWindowPos(hDWP, child->m_hWnd, 0, 0, 0, r.Width(), r.Height(),
                SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
        }
    }

    ::EndDeferWindowPos(hDWP);
    GetClientRect(&save_rc);
    Invalidate(TRUE);
}
```

However, if I change the look and feel of my property sheet like this:

```
SetIconsList(IDB_MAINT_DB_LARGE, 32);
SetLook(CMFCPropertySheet::PropSheetLook_OutlookBar);
```

And then I resize my property sheet:

[image: Outlook Bar]

How do we adjust `OnSize` to leave the outlook bar width alone? We only need to resize the height.

There is this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378408/dynamically-resizing-cmfcpropertysheet-with-propsheetlook-onenotetabs-style/7961917) and associated answers but the link in the answer to a Microsoft Knowledge base article is not working. Either way, `OnSize` needs to be customised to render the `PropSheetLook_OutlookBar` correctly. Somehow ...

## Update

According to Spy it is a toolbar:

[image: Spy results]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I did was add this to my resizing class header:

```
protected:
    CWnd* InitNavigationControl() override;
private:
    CWnd * m_pNavigationControl;
```

Then, I added this to the source file:

```
CWnd* CResizingMFCPropertySheet::InitNavigationControl()
{
    m_pNavigationControl = CMFCPropertySheet::InitNavigationControl();

    return m_pNavigationControl;
}
```

Finally, I adjusted the `OnSize` method:

```
void CResizingMFCPropertySheet::OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy)
{
    CMFCPropertySheet::OnSize(nType, cx, cy);

    if (!GetActivePage()) return;
    if (!GetTabControl()) return;

    if (nType == SIZE_MINIMIZED)
        return;

    int dx = cx - save_rc.Width();
    int dy = cy - save_rc.Height();

    int count = 0;
    for (CWnd *child = GetWindow(GW_CHILD); child; child = child->GetWindow(GW_HWNDNEXT))
        count++;

    HDWP hDWP = ::BeginDeferWindowPos(count);
    for (CWnd *child = GetWindow(GW_CHILD); child; child = child->GetWindow(GW_HWNDNEXT))
    {
        bool move = false;

        //If you add child controls manually, you want to move not resize
        if(child == &m_lblResize && m_lblResize.GetSafeHwnd() != nullptr)
            move = true;

        CRect r;
        child->GetWindowRect(&r);
        ScreenToClient(&r);

        if (move || child->SendMessage(WM_GETDLGCODE) & DLGC_BUTTON)
        {
            //move the main buttons and the child controls
            r.left += dx;
            r.top += dy;
            ::DeferWindowPos(hDWP, child->m_hWnd, 0, r.left, r.top, 0, 0,
                SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
        }
        else
        {
            if (child->GetSafeHwnd() == m_pNavigationControl->GetSafeHwnd())
            {
                r.bottom += dy;
                ::DeferWindowPos(hDWP, child->m_hWnd, nullptr,
                    r.left, r.top, r.Width(), r.Height(),
                    SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
            }
            else
            {
                //this must be a child window, resize it
                r.right += dx;
                r.bottom += dy;
                ::DeferWindowPos(hDWP, child->m_hWnd, 0, 0, 0, r.Width(), r.Height(),
                    SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
            }
        }
    }

    ::EndDeferWindowPos(hDWP);
    GetClientRect(&save_rc);
    Invalidate(TRUE);
}
```

As you can see, we were able to test against the handler for the navigation control. So the result:

[image: Bar]